# Module accidentally removed

Tags: 8

Somehow, I accidentally deleted the *shield* folder after installing the [Shield](https://www.drupal.org/project/shield) module, and now I can't disable it. I can't work on my site.

Can anyone please tell me how to disable the module?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the folder you deleted back where it was.

Then you'll be able to uninstall the module as normal.

Comment: Thank you . I put the folder back to the module  and the set $user = '' in ShieldMiddleware but its not working. I just need to disable the shield, Is there any way to disable the module from database ?

Comment: @Jahir7 `but its not working` did you get an error or what?